# MAX is not a recognized table hints option

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Issue:

Create a table using a stored procedure in SQL 2012. I have used "MAX" in the past to get a maximum value but get the following error this time:

*"MAX" is not a recognized table hints option. If it is intended as a parameter to a table-valued function or to the CHANGETABLE function, ensure that your database compatibility mode is set to 90.*

I have tried without the Max and the routine runs but of course would give the wrong value, I have also tried *As FieldNameX* but this did not help.

Aim:

To get the maximum value of the linked column in the secondary table. i.e Table1 has a ID of xyz and Table2 has three listings of xyz, "1", "2", and "3" and so it should get "3" as the value to put into the new table.

Code:

```
USE [Database]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spPropertyListBCP]
(
    @tableName NVARCHAR(256)     
)
AS
BEGIN 
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)


SET @sql = 'SELECT p.ID AS UniqueID
INTO ' + @tableName  + ' FROM TblProperty AS p
(
MAX(T2.ValueField),
p.BuildingNo,
p.Street 
)
JOIN
TblTable2 as T2 on p.ID= T2.ID'
EXEC (@sql)
END
```

Research:

Among others ~ [SQL Server 2005 Error - ""MAX" is not a recognized table hints option"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416260/sql-server-2005-error-max-is-not-a-recognized-table-hints-option) which appears to pivot but I don't believe is exactly what I am after

Comment: `FROM table AS p (MAX().....)` isn't valid syntax. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Small code amendment I've made. Table1 (TblProperty) has a unqiue list of IDs. Table2 has a list with these IDs but the ID will appear multiple times. I want to use the ID to search Table2 and get the highest value of column x in the second table

Comment: Are those supposed to be additional columns for the dynamically generated table? As a side note I would recommend a couple changes to your procedure. You should change the datatype for @tableName to sysname instead of nvarchar (there is no need to use extended characters in a table name). Secondly I would suggest wrapping your variable in QUOTENAME in your dynamic sql to prevent sql injection.

Comment: Have you noticed that you're missing a quote somewhere before `EXEC(@SQL)`?

Comment: Copy/Paste Error that... I'll amend as that's not it, in this case

Comment: @SeanLange Actually, sysname it's the same as `NVARCHAR(128)`. And @indofraiser, you should research how to use `MAX`

Comment: Instead of executing the dynamic SQL, `PRINT @sql` so that you can see what is being built before executing it. Maybe the error will be easier for you to spot.

Comment: @Lamak I know it is a synonym for that. In this post you could end up with a value longer than will fit because the parameter is twice the length.

Comment: I know the max length now so will shortern it to 20 or is sysname better up to 128?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a shot in the dark based on a pretty vague explanation of requirements.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spPropertyListBCP]
(
    @tableName sysname
)
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

    set @sql = 'SELECT p.UPRN AS UPRN
        , MAX(T2.ValueField) As ValueFieldName
        , p.BuildingNo
        , p.Street 
    INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName)  + ' 
    FROM TblProperty AS p
    JOIN TblTable2 as T2 on p.ID = T2.ID
    GROUP BY p.UPRN
        , p.BuildingNo
        , p.Street';

    exec sp_executesql @sql
END
```

Comment: When doing a SELECT...INTO, you need to make sure all columns are named. That MAX function needs some kind of alias on it.

Comment: Hi, I worked it out at about the same time, It was really the Group by I was not 'seeing'.

Comment: @MartinSoles agreed. This of course is untested code based on an extremely loose definition.